# Python turtle 3.7 why am I not getting screen after the code written below?

Tags: python, python-3.7, python-turtle

```py
from turtle import *

s = turtle()
```

why I am not getting any output? Error is occurring, saying turtle is not defined? It's python 3.7

Answer (score 0):

`s = turtle()` statement is meant to create object of class `turtle`. But in module [turtle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html) there is no class by this name. That's why you're getting error `NameError: name 'turtle' is not defined`.

Turtle module is meant for simple drawings. You don't need to create any object (of any class) to start. Just call any drawing function straight away (and read module [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html)), for example:

```py
from turtle import *

circle(50)
done()
```

---

More complex example taken from module [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html):

```py
from turtle import *
color('red', 'yellow')
begin_fill()
while True:
    forward(200)
    left(170)
    if abs(pos()) < 1:
        break
end_fill()
done()
```

will visualize this picture:

[image]